# How To Remove AFTER & BEFORE "something text" with RegEx Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following lines of text and I want to delete the lines before and after a block of lines that are to be retained.

```
Asdldgsd asfasfasf
Sdfgsdf fgsdg sdfgdsg
Adsfasdfa sdfgdfgdf asdgethg

How To ABCD
keyword...keyword...keyword
End Of EFG

Dfsdjrgishfr sdghdtrhetr sdfgwsergsdf
Fdghetr adfghe56 wdfhe56y sdfhr575
Aergetry 57jegrhed wtfrhjryutgh
Adgfe56 jn37hwsdfghdfj gjkmfghwtrh
```

After deleting the unwanted lines the file should be as follows:

```
How To ABCD
keyword...keyword...keyword
End Of EFG
```

Comment: Could you clarify? Should the 'Before' become 'After'? Like something like [this](http://regex101.com/r/bQ7jE7)?

Comment: fix, thanks for Jerry

Comment: I have tried to clarify the question and keep the original text. If my change does not correctly state your question then please edit it again.

Comment: Does notepad++ suppose the "dotall" flag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assuming notepad supports the "dotall" flag):

```
search: (?s).*(How To ABCD.*End Of EFG).*
replace: \1
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the option `. matches newline`:

Regex:
`.*?(^How To ABCD$.*?^End Of EFG$).*`

Replacement:
`\1`

Strangely Notpad++ Regex engine supports newline `^` and end line `$` anchors within a regex when using checking the `. matches newline` option.

[image]